# Dealing with floating point imprecisions in a 2D Tiled based game

Tags: unity, sprites, tilemap

I'm using unity3d to create a little horizontal tile based platformer game. My entities have a rectangle defining their collision volume.

On the other hand I'm using a camera configured to  1 unit = 1 pixel because I like to work in pixels instead of units.

The problem is that my sprites are created in a higher resolution and I have to scale them down to allow correct size. So, they do not have integer size in any dimension. For example I'm testing with a sprite that after scaling becomes something like 60.12px in height.

My problem is that when I try to check for collision against tiles some times, there are float precision errors and I come into problems like detecting if a tile is in front of the player wrongly because of the bottom part of the sprite getting into the floor tiles.

How do you deal with this? I have tried to add a little amount to somehow fix that but it does not work quite well.

Cheers.

Comment: Doesn't really sound like a fpp error, rather something in the code. Wrong rounding, accidental rounding, conflict between the scaled and non-scaled numbers...? Precision problems would occur if you move the calculation far away from zero (eg. do 100000 + 0.01 in Single precision) or hugely scale up a minor fp imprecision (accumulate).

Comment: I will look into it... thanks for pointing that out

Comment: As I suspected, this is a floating point error. My sprites, when are scaled to fit current resolution become of sizes like 29.999998. I must blame Debug.Log unity funciton for rounding the result and not showing the real result.

Comment: Ok. That number is a typical integer value that is held in 32-bit single-precision floating point space. Singles give 7 significant numbers, and in this number the 8th is fuzzy (doubles give ca 14 significants). It's not really an error, rather an effect of the fp formats. Tricky sometimes, indeed :-). You can always round to closest integer with floor(value + 0.5) or scaleup/round/scalebackdown. Good luck with the numeric spaces!

Comment: Could you add an image or two of the problem?